# Redirect IP address request to domain name in node express

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a frontend `React TypeScript` and backend REST API `Django Python`. I build my frontend app and receive the `build` folder, and have set a proxy to my backend REST API on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` with URLs starting with `/api/`. I have deployed these apps in a `Centos` server, in the folder `app` along with a `server.ts` file and run my applications with `node server.ts`. I also have Cloudflare set up to point my domain address to my `Centos` server IP address. I need to prevent my server from being accessed directly from the IP address. I need to redirect the IP address request to my domain name. I know how to do it in `Apache` server but I don't know how to do it in Node Express.

`server.ts`

```
const express = require("express"),
            fs = require("fs"),
            https = require("https"),
            { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware"),
            path = require("path");



const app = express();

/* Serve static files from the build directory */
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

/* Forward requests to /api to your server */
app.use("/api/", createProxyMiddleware({ target: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", changeOrigin: true }));

/* Serve index.html for all other requests */
app.get('*', (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html")); });



/* Create HTTPS server */
https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync("PATH/privkey.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("PATH/fullchain.pem")
}, app).listen(443);
```